# Creating and killing processes and child processes completely

Tags: perl, process, parent-child

I have a program which is in Windows from the command prompt using a command like this

```
C:\Users\AndyI> ./myprogram.exe datafile.txt
```

I want to use a Perl program to create many instances of `datafile.txt` (say, `datafile.001.txt`, `datafile.002.txt` etc.) and call `myprogram.exe` to process them in parallel.

I've had problems illustrated by this generic program

```
$exit  = '';
$count = 0;

while ( $exit eq '' ) {

    $pid = fork();

    if ( $pid == 0 ) {          # if this is a child process
        $exit = 'yes';
        system 'notepad.exe';   # open an instance of Notepad
    }
    else {
        system("taskkill /im notepad.exe /f");  # Kill all instances
        $count++;
        print "$count instances\n";
    }

    if ( $count > 500 ) {       # In case of infinite loop
        $exit = 'yes';
    }
}

sleep 100;      # So I have time to read the output
```

I am using `fork()` to create child processes, and each child uses `system` to start up an instance of Notepad. The parent process attempts to kill the Notepad process with `taskkill`, and this repeats in a loop.

The program generates (and kills) only 64 instances of Notepad before halting. It's clear that I'm not handling these processes properly and there are bits hanging around which fill up some kind of table.

If I don't kill Notepad there is still a limit of 64. This perhaps indicates that my cleanup isn't working and I've killed the Notepad process but let the child live.

Oddly the `system` call yields a negative `$pid` but those PIDs are not recognised by `taskkill` or Task Manager.

How do I generate and kill many instances of Notepad without hitting the limit?

**EDIT**:  Following mob's thoughts, here's another script, but it still won't let me spawn and kill more than 64 Notepads:
    $exit='';
    $count=0;

```
while($exit eq ''){

    $pid=system 1,'notepad.exe';       # open an instance of Notepad
    print "$pid\n";
    sleep 1;        # Slows it down for easy viewing - not necessary
    system("taskkill /pid $pid /f");      # Kill by PID
    $count++;
    print"$count instances\n";

    if($count>100){     # in case of infinite loop!
        $exit='yes';
    }

}

sleep 100;      # so I have time to read the output!
```

Any thoughts?  I haven't found a use for waitpid or wait - can you clarify what you mean?  I need to kill, not wait.  (again, not a phrase for search engines!).

**EDIT2**:  `Parallel::ForkManager` (thanks Borodin!)

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $pm=Parallel::ForkManager->new(20);    # maximum number of child processes at any one time

PROGS:
for(my $i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    print"$i\n";
    sleep 1;
    $pm->start and next PROGS;
    my $pid=system 1,'notepad.exe';
    sleep 10;
    system("taskkill /pid $pid /f");
    $pm->finish;
}
```

This essentially does what the first edit does, but somehow does it more cleanly - perhaps scrubbing away the remnants of the child that the earlier effort did.  I would still love to know why!

Every second, it kicks off a child process which runs the code between `$pm->start` and `$pm->finish`.  That child lives for 10s before killing Notepad and dying, which allows about 10 Notepads to live at any one time.  And they vital thing is that more than 64 Notepads can live and die before the whole program exits.

I had wanted to kill each program from the main process, but as I will know when I want it do die before I start it, this ought to work.

Lots more to try - thanks for the help so far, and you can call this solved (ish).

Comment: `fork` isn't provided by Windows so it is *emulated* by the perl interpreter. It assigns negative numbers to the emulated processes to distinguish them from real Windows processes.

Comment: Do you realise that the parent process will issue the `taskkill` *immediately after* the `fork`, and quite possibly before the new child has started a Notepad process? Also, each new child process will start a copy of Notepad, skip the `if ( $count > 500 )` test because its copy of `$count` is zero, and then go to the top of the `while` loop and call `fork` itself. So every child as well as the parent is repeatedly starting new child processes. I'm sure that's not what you want. You shouldn't need to `kill` the child processes: they can be left to just `exit` when they are done.

Comment: You may want to look at [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) to make this easier to write.

Comment: Are you sure that you will gain anything by running multiple copies of your program in parallel? If the process is disk-bound then all children will be queueing up for their turn to read/write the disk, and the overall time taken will only be significantly sorter if there is some processor-heavy work for one to do while another is waiting for its disk operation to finish.

Comment: `taskkill` can be delayed by `sleep` until the child is well and truly done, with no negative effects either way.  When the child is spawned it sees `$exit` as 'yes' so it kicks off one Notepad and exits.

Comment: Killing the child processes of the original perl script isn't the problem, it's killing the Notepads.  That's exactly what I want to do - my real program (a commercial package) needs to be timed out in a programmable way if it's taking too long and doesn't provide a way of doing so itself (or is there another way to time out a process started by `system`?).  And my real program does gain by running instances in parallel as it's doing serious number crunching (in fact its documentation suggests it's worthwhile), though the disc access will be an issue to some extent.

Comment: Will look at `Parallel::Forkmanager`, which certainly _sounds_ useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, and on Windows, you might want to try the [underdocumented `system 1, LIST` syntax](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlport#system).

> `system(1, @args)` spawns an external process and immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to terminate.  Return value
>   may be used subsequently in "wait" or "waitpid".

Importantly, the return value is a proper process id that can be passed to `taskkill` (as well as to Perl's `waitpid`), not a *pseudo-process id* (a negative number) that you get from a `fork` call on Windows. There is no need to use a `fork` call with this syntax.

```
$n = "001";
while (-f "datafile$n.txt") {
    $pid = system 1, "fancyprogram.exe", "datafile$n.txt";
    $n++;
    ...
}
```

A module like [`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super) could also help a lot in a script with a lot of background processes to manage. Some of the ways it could help are in throttling the number of background jobs (running only as many jobs at a time as your system can reasonably handle), settings timeouts on background jobs, or setting priorities or CPU affinity on jobs.

Comment: Thanks, mob.  I'll edit my question to insert my latest effort, which still isn't quite there.  I'll look into `Forks::Super` too.